# Love2D making self-executable with no unpacking

Tags: android, lua, love2d

Im create simple game, remake my old ZX-Spectrum game "m2k"

Love2D is simple engine using LUA.

What i need:
Compile Love2D -> exe files, linux binary, android apk.

Goal is pack Win32, Linux64 bit and android apk WITHOUT possiblity of just unpacking .love file and WITHOUT manual installing love2d engine.
https://pp.userapi.com/c637425/v637425257/4a8a8/QCv9Q5dz_b4.jpg

I cannot found anything useful about it. I found LoveExporter 0.2 by shake but this utilite fails compiling normal binary. It fails with error.

All manuals tell me just create .love file and send it to all. No way. 
It's no good for me.

Maybe i can run this utilite.  I fails with 0.2 version maybe 0.1 works
http://snake174.github.io/html/programs/love_exporter.html
Partially it works, but it requires Microsoft Windows, and android support is broken. Developer not create new versions about a year +.

I don't want to pay for windows, reboot to windows or another using unsafe OS, and requires Native full work analog.
etc

Compile Love2D -> exe files, linux binary, android apk.

Comment: Have you tried [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/) instead of Love2d? This is for game development on LUA too. And It can build app for many platforms.

Comment: Game is already full written today in Love2D . Just needed simple and fast compiling with icon and etc to three systems.    . Corona SDK is a bad SDK like Cryengine SDK  - it not work with Linux even under wine,  i just delete it. I don't want rewrite game in another language or engine.  it 150kb code and 129 levels.

Comment: Screenshot. https://pp.userapi.com/c637424/v637424257/48c3e/hZIGybPqDWg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The wiki already has a guide for creating executables for Windows, Linux, Mac and Android. Unless I'm misunderstanding your request, you need [this.](https://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution#Creating_a_Windows_Executable)

Comment: I requires  binary files without love2D and .lua or .love files in one "packet".  etc - User runs  game.run  and plays game.  No dependencies , or etc.  I already found for exe - LoveExporter01 (only for LOVE 0.9.1) and Startdev android fast packaging  (of course outdated and for LOVE 0.10.1 ) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAZo-pin4nE     I dont want waste a time with SDK, NDK,MDK, TDK ... just click make apk and run.  And Im search all-in-one compiler for Linux.  For windows unfortunately i requires stop work and reboot. and all compilers wherei fourd is OUTDATED.  Now exist 0.10.2 ver

Comment: I thinking continue using Loveexporter01 and Start Gamedev. Unfortunately no other methods found